# Как поместить ProgressBar в Activity чтоб он как бы показался поверх?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

У меня есть класс `AsyncTask` который делает загрузку, и само собой пока идет загрузка должен выводиться крутящийся по кругу `ProgressBar`.

Реализация самого `ProgressBar` понятна, но как сделать так, чтоб активити в котором начинается загрузка как бы немного затемнялось и в центре начал крутиться `ProgressBar`, в конце загрузки это все исчезает и остается только активити поверх которого `ProgressBar` вызывался...

Я подумал сделать так, в `AsyncTask` в методе `onPreExecute()` послать интент чтоб открыть другое активити, которое будет полупрозрачное и в нем установить `ProgressBar`, когда `AsyncTask` отработает то в методе `onPostExecute()` закрыть активити...

Но мне кажется это кривая идея...
**Подскажите как это делается правильно?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте для таких целей [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Добавьте стиль:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

и

```
<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

цвет:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

и вызывайте диалог

```
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(),R.style.MyTheme);
 progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
 progressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
 progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: да но мне не совсем это нужно. Меня интересует вот такая ситуация, представьте себе экран девайса с содержимым(вью и прочее), и вот когда юзер нажимает на "Заргузить", то экран как бы покрывается полупрозрачным серым фотом и в центре которого крутиться диалог... Вопрос в том как закрыть экран полупрозрачным фотом и поместить в центр диалог.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko , обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Объявите в вашем активити

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
```

Когда надо показать диалог с крутящимся спиннером вызывайте этот метод:

```
private void showProgress(String text) {

        if (progressDialog == null) {
            try {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", text);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

    }
```

Когда надо скрывать, этот

```
public void hideProgress() {

        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Мне кажется вы не до конца поняли мой вопрос... Следуя Вашему ответу, вы просто показываете как включить и выколючить диалог, это я знаю. Меня интересует вот такая ситуация, представьте  себе экран девайса с содержимым(вью и прочее), и вот когда юзер нажимает на "Заргузить", то экран как бы покрывается полупрозрачным серым фотом и в центре которого крутиться диалог... Вопрос в том как закрыть экран полупрозрачным фотом и поместить в центр диалог.

Comment: Если бы вы попробовали использовать код, то увидели бы что он делает то что вы и просили

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Спасибо, это то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Ну если все варианты которые тебе предложили выше не подходят, тогда ты можешь извратится, это вопрос техники верстки. Примерно так в твоей xml разметке добавляешь RelativeLayout вну три которого будут все твои вьюхи и поверх твоего контента добавляешь еще какой-нибудь RelativeLayout ставишь ему бекграунд с прозрачностью добавляешь в него по центру ProgressBar и все готово, когда нужно показать делаешь relativeLayuot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), когда надо скрыть relativeLayuot.setVisibility(View.GONE).