# Application перед запуском основной активити

Tags: android

Подскажите, как реализован функционал загрузки то ли wallpaper, то ли какой другой активности перед запуском основного приложения, это первый вопрос.
И второй - заключается в том, какими методами лучше всего показать пользователю подождать? 
Проблема состоит в том, что многие данные подгружаются с интернета, поэтому ждать приходится. Хотелось бы как-то греить экран(как при вызове алерт диалога) и делать это элегантно, не стандартным progressbar'om.

Comment: ну, сделайте кастомный диалог, который и показывайте. Непонятно, в чем конкретно ваша проблема?

Comment: про кастомный диалог - это примерно понятно, я хотел бы посмотреть примеры или послушать советы, как это лучше сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Можете добавить `Activity`, которая будет выступать в роли заставки. А по истечении заданного времени запускать уже нужную.

2 Можете взять вариант из [этого вопроса:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515097/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-progressbar-%D0%B2-activity-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85/515098#515098)

Задаете стили

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

в `colors.xml`

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

и вызываете:

```
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(),R.style.MyTheme);
 progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
 progressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
 progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы натолкнули меня на нужную ветку. А можете подробнее рассказать по первому пункту?

Comment: @IvanVovk Ну например ваша первая `activity` отображает только какую-то заставку (картинку с прогрессбаром), а через 2 секунды, к примеру, Вы запускаете уже главную `Activity` приложения из нее.